# parsing xml using cakephp Xml::build

Tags: xml, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i an following this article from cookbook. 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html#Xml::build

```
$xmlpath   =     WWW_ROOT.'files/xml/'.$xmldetails['Xml']['xml_url'];
        App::uses('Xml', 'Utility'); 
        if(file_exists($xmlpath)){
            $parsed_xml = Xml::build($xmlpath, array('return' => 'simplexml'));
            pr($parsed_xml);
            die();
        }
```

this is the code that i write in the controller's method. I get

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Xml::build()
```

i am not sure y i get this.

any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you are using CakePHP 2.X?

Comment: @noslone i did  echo Configure::version(); and the out put was 2.1.2

Comment: That codes works here. I think there is something wrong with the directory structure of you CakePHP installation. It looks like the `Xml` utility is never loaded. Can you confirm that `/lib/Cake/Utility/Xml.php` exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your data you have `$xmldetails['Xml']` which I assume is a model. If this is the case you have already imported a class called `Xml` so cake will not import another.

If you want to use cakes `Xml` class, you can **not** have a model called `Xml`.